# JOIN not recognizing filenames stored in MAPFILE elements

Tags: bash, join

I am attempting to join 65 files by a shared lookup column, the first column. I am testing portions of the code on the command line and have issues with the MAPFILE elements as input of JOIN. I have unsuccessfully tried several different methods of echoing the elements of MAPFILE. When I replace the elements with the file names they represent, it works correctly. How can I pass the elements of MAPFILE to JOIN?

```
cat list.txt | ( mapfile -t; echo "${MAPFILE[@]}" ) | join -11 -21 -a1 -a2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -e0 ${MAPFILE[1]} ${MAPFILE[2]} >countmatrix.txt
```

Other strategies attempted:

```
cat list.txt | ( mapfile -t; echo "${MAPFILE[@]}" ) | (file1=$(echo ${MAPFILE[1]}); file2=$(echo ${MAPFILE[2]})) | join -1 -2 -a -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -e0 $file1 $file2 >countmatrix.txt

cat list.txt | ( mapfile -t; echo "${MAPFILE[@]}" ) | (file1=$(echo ${MAPFILE[1]}); file2=$(echo ${MAPFILE[2]}); join -11 -21 -a1 -a2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -e0 <(sort $file1) <(sort $file2) >countmatrix.txt)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output, say with 2 or 3 files rather than 65 of them?

Comment: The input is list.txt which is a list of filenames each appearing on a new line. There is no output in the first line of code because join throws an extra operand error. The other strategies output countmatrix.txt as an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both quoted attempts fail to work since they try to read the MAPFILE in one sub-shell, and use the values in second sub-shell of a pipe. In sh* shells, variable are passed from parent sub-shell into child sub-shell. Each element of a pipe is executed in a sub-shell that is a children of the main shell.

As a result, variables from one part of the pipe are not available to other parts of the pipe. (e.g `A=5 | echo $A` will not work).

In this case:

1. The '(mapfile ...)' is executed in sub-shell, reading MAPFILE
2. The 'join' is executed in a separate unrelated sub-shell, can not use MAPFILE

Simple solution will be to read the map file in the main shell (or intermediate sub-shell), as shown below

```
# Read MAPFLE
mapfile -t < list.txt
# EXecute join, use  MAPFILE
join -11 -21 -a1 -a2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -e0 ${MAPFILE[1]} ${MAPFILE[2]} >countmatrix.txt
```

On surface, there is no need to pipe anything into the join command, which is using named files for input (ignoring stdin).

The "real" solution (65 files) should include the join inside a loop, instead of a single join.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. In the final script join exists in a for loop over the contents of the MAPFILE array. I was attempting to validate the script components on the command line before running the final script when I encountered this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `mapfile` in the subshell and the assigned variable
`${MAPFILE[@]}` is inaccessible from the parent process.

Please try something like:

```
cat list.txt | ( mapfile -t; echo "${MAPFILE[@]:0:2}" ) | xargs join -11 -21 -a1 -a2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -e0 > countmatrix.txt
```

Considering the case the filenames defined in `list.txt` contain whitespaces
and/or other special characters, it will be safer to say:

```
cat list.txt | ( mapfile -t; printf "%s\0" "${MAPFILE[@]:0:2}" ) | xargs -0 join -11 -21 -a1 -a2 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 -e0 > countmatrix.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about child and parent processes. xargs fails because MAPFILE is longer than 2 elements and join interprets the additional elements as extra operands.

Comment: Understood. I've corrected my answer accordingly. However if you are going to refer to the remaining (3rd or later) elements in `${MAPFILE[@]}` subsequently, it will be better to execute `mapfile` in the parent (current) process as @dash-o writes.